# Mounting USB flash disk in read only mode

Tags: usb, fedora-15

I have a Fedora 15 box, which is on a public network. How do I configure it such that when non-root users plug in a USB drive, the box mounts it as a read-only device.

Answer (score 0):

Typical Fedora installation uses `gnome-volume-manager`. I suggest you look into that. I use KDE and it has it's own Device Manager.

Alternatively, you can of course create an entry to `/etc/fstab` manually and give it the permissions and options you want. Relevant `mount` options in this case would be `ro user auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look for udev rules, check here for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev

See also the last example on http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/06/some-nifty-udev-rules-and-examples/ , as it shows how to spawn your own script when a USB drive is connected. From there, you could even open a popup to warn the user at this stage and mount or remount the USB drive accordingly (eg. with `mount -o remount -r /mymountpoint`)